# 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes: truncated \xXX escape Mac OS

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to read a file (MacOS)

```
file_path = r'xml/J96-3004.xml'
with open (file_path, 'r', encoding='unicode-escape') as f:
    contents = f.read()
```

**I've looked through all the possible information, none of it works:**

- using a raw string

```
file_path = r'xml/J96-3004.xml'
with open (file_path, 'r', encoding='unicode-escape') as f:
    contents = f.read()
```

- using pathlib

```
from pathlib import Path
data_folder = Path('xml')
file_path = data_folder / "J96-3004.xml"
with open (file_path, 'r', encoding='unicode-escape') as f:
    contents = f.read()
```

- using os.path

```
import os
file_path = os.path.join(path, "J96-3004.xml")
with open (file_path, 'r', encoding='unicode-escape') as f:
    contents = f.read()
```

- use // instead of / ; and "" instead of ''
- use encoding 'utf-8', 'windows-1251'

There is an error occurs "'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes: truncated \xXX escape Mac OS
"

Is there an another solution?

Comment: is it possible to share some of the file? I am unable to replicate your error by using my own xml file

Comment: thanks for your quiestion - the problem was not with the name of file - but with a content of file. I check through the text - it was a word "1j\xia" - this is the problem. Now I'm thinking about how to get around this problem.